# INDEX MATCH on a cell that has data separated by a comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have a JIRA dump of data. I am trying to match a JIRA ID with a name - however the cell i need to match against can have more than one JIRA ID present.

For example - i have a tab with table of Requirements with their JIRA IDs.

```
    ColA         ColB    
   JIRA-111      Req1
   JIRA-222      Req2 
   JIRA-333      Req3
```

I then have a dump from JIRA with lots of linked issues where i want to match the ColA above with the data sheet and pull the ColB name next to it. The issue is, the cell can have more than 1 JIRA ID.

```
ColA                                 ColB
JIRA-111, JIRA-123, JIRA-456         (Want to return here Req1, that matches JIRA-111)
JIRA-222                             (Req2 would be returned)
JIRA-333, JIRA-678                   (want to return here Req3, that matches JIRA-333)
```

Is there a way i can run a VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH that can search a cell with multiple (,) and return a value if any of the values match the look up table?

Comment: Is the first JIRA ID always the one you want to search on? If there are more than 1 JIRA IDs, is there the possibility they would relate to different Req numbers?

Comment: No the requirement will be unique to one JIRA. There should not be multiple requirements.  The other linked JIRAs will be defects. Normally the requirement will be the first linked JIRA.

Comment: Are the Jira IDs always the same length and format?

Comment: As the number grows it will jump from single, to double, to triple numbers. ex. JIRA-1, JIRA-11, JIRA-111. The word will always stay the same. The number will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the same setup**

Sheet 1 A2:A4 contains comma delimited data

Sheet 'JIRA ID' A2:A4 contains JIRA ID mappings

**Formula in Sheet 1 B2:**

```
=INDEX('JIRA ID'!B:B,MATCH(LEFT(A2,(IFERROR((SEARCH(",",A2)-1),len(a2)))),'JIRA ID'!A:A,0))
```

It does assume that the JIRA ID you're looking for is the first one in the comma delimited list. If that isn't always the case then this won't work for you

Comment: Boom! this has worked. You're right it'll only work if the JIRA ID i need is first. And in 99% of cases it should be. I'll use this for now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not massive on my formulas, What's LEN do?

Comment: LEN(A2) returns the number of characters in cell A2. In this case we are taking the leftmost x digits in cell A2, where x is either the position before the first comma or the total length of the cell if there are no commas. The result of that is then used as the lookup value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below `LOOKUP` formula which will do it.

**Setup**

Sheet 1 A2:A4 contains comma delimited data

Sheet 'JIRA ID' A2:A4 contains JIRA ID mappings

**Formula in Sheet 1 B2:**

```
=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH('JIRA ID'!$A$2:$A$4&",",Sheet1!A2&",",1),'JIRA ID'!$B$2:$B$4)
```

**Tweaked formula as per OP's input: (for entire column)"**

```
=LOOKUP(2^15,1/(SEARCH('Test Reqs'!B:B&",",'Test Case Execution'!W89&",",1)*('Test Reqs'!B:B<>"")),'Test Reqs'!C:C)
```

Caution: Entire column ranges will make the formula calculation slow and therefore will affect performance.

Comment: Hi thanks! I've just tried this (making it fit my data set) and at the moment it's just returning the number 0. So i'm understanding the formula, what is the 2^15 achieving?

Comment: @PaulHunt I have tested the formula before posting. Can you explain your data layout and the formula?

Comment: This is the formula as i changed it =LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH('Test Reqs'!B:B&",",'Test Case Execution'!W89&",",1),'Test Reqs'!C:C)                  Test Regs being the JIRA ID worksheet. B = the column with the Key. C = The name of the test requirement. Test Case ExecutionW89 was the cell i was looking up against. It has two JIRA IDs in it separated by a comma

Comment: @PaulHunt I understood now. The range from "Test Reqs" must be exact i.e. 'Test Reqs'!B1:B900 and without blanks. But if it is challenging to limit it thus then I see that you have a working solution. Also, I am posting a tweak which shall work in your case.